# How do I duplicate multiple items in a list by numbers in another list: python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, duplicates

So I want to take a list and duplicate each element of the list. The number of times each element is to be duplicated should correspond to the number with the same index in another list making a new list.

example:

```
list1 = [2,4,6]

list2 = [3,4,2]
```

I want new list to be

```
list3 = [2,2,2,4,4,4,4,6,6].
```

Here is What I have tried:

```
t = [1,2,3]
k = [2,3,4]
t =list(map(int,t))
k = list(map(int,k))
for i in range(t):
    m =[]
    for i in range(k):
        m[i]=t[i]*k[i]
        m.append
        print(m)
```

Answer (score 3):

you could try this using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?itertools.chain.from_iterable#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
from itertools import chain

list1 = [2, 4, 6]
list2 = [3, 4, 2]

ret = list(chain.from_iterable(n * [item] for item, n in zip(list1, list2)))
print(ret)  # [2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6]
```

`n * [item]` will be `3 * [2] = [2, 2, 2]` in the first iteration; all i do then is chain those elements to a list using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`.

or, using [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.repeat):

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

ret = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(item, n) for item, n in zip(list1, list2)))
print(ret)  # [2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6]
```